# Fitnesse: Slim server died issue

Tags: ios, fitnesse, acceptance-testing, fitnesse-slim

I am trying to add the Fitnesse testing tool for iOS app testing. I created sample test. When I clicked on test button, I am getting following error.

> Unable to start test system 'slim': fitnesse.slim.SlimError: Error
>   SLiM server died before a connection could be established. [OCSP_INFO]
>   ERROR: Use '$ npm install ios-sim -g'

It looks like server connection is not created. How to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you open your `terminal`, enter the `npm install ios-sim -g` look what happen?

Comment: @aircraft Yes after installing node and entering above command in terminal it works.